# VC dimension of a quadratic binary classifier

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

Assume we have a set of training data $\{\boldsymbol{x}_i, y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ from $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{-1, 1\}$. The hypotheses $\mathcal{H} $ are all classifiers with the form $\hat{y} = \text{sign}(\boldsymbol{v}^T \tilde{\boldsymbol{x}})$, where $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{R}^5$ and $\tilde{\boldsymbol{x}} = (x_1, x_2, x_1^2, x_1 x_2, x_2^2)$.

I know there exists a set of 5 element that can be shattered by $\mathcal{H}$, but does a set of 6 exist, or can it be proved that any set of 6 element cannot be shattered by $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible to prove the VC dimension without trying all combinations exhaustively.